# bootcamp drivers

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have a early 2008 mac and i just installed win 7 via bootcamp on it.

When i try to install the drivers (provided via apple download, when kicking off the whole process) i get a "Bootcamp x64 is unsupported on this computer model"! I'm quite lost here i need guidance... on apple download site there a bunch o versions and they all seem the same...

Where can i get the appropriate package?!? Or maybe which one should i download?!?

PS: my whole setup is 64 bits, incluiding windows...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clear matrix showing the proper download link of the necessary `Boot Camp Support Software` depending on your mac model and the Windows version you want to use: [Bootcamp Drivers](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634)

Answer (score 0):

You might try manually installing the drivers you need (display, keyboard, etc) instead of letting bootcamp do it. Since it is failing anyway. Try extracting he drivers if they are in a package and use Windoze control panel to add them.